# SQLAlchemy with_for_update lock not working?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, locking, flask-sqlalchemy

I tried to run two transactions in two different sessions

In session 1-

```
user=User.query.with_for_update(of=User,read=False).filter(User.id==123).first()
```

In session 2 -

```
user=User.query.filter(User.id==123).first()
```

Why does the DB allow the session 2 to read the same row I have already locked for update in session 1 and haven't ended the transaction?

Comment: The latter SELECT has no explicit locking applied, so why should it be blocked? Could you explain why you think it shouldn't be able to read it?

Comment: my concepts regarding locking are not very clear ....could you help know if i update a X attribute of user in session 2 and 1 i.e increment X attribute's value by one, session 2 will wait till session 1 transaction is commited, then session 2 transaction will also commit, In the end X attribute of user will only increment by 1 not by 2 right as session 1 changes werent conveyed to session 2 ?

Comment: @SanilJain - SQLAlchemy with_for_update lock not working? - works fine. try to add `sleep(60)` into script 1(before `commit()`) and try to select the record in script 2

Comment: Could you please edit that comment into the question itself, maybe with some examples of what you'd expect to happen (vs. what happens).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59377828/flask-alchemy-with-for-update-row-locking-not-working ....@IljaEverilä please help me here