# SQLAlchemy with_for_update row locking not working?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, locking, flask-sqlalchemy

There is a student whose `type` attribute is 4 and the minimum value for `type` attribute  can be 1.

**In postgres**

In session 1, I exclusively lock and update a row in the student table:

```sql
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE students IN ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = 122  FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE students SET type = 1 WHERE id = 122;
END;
```

In session 2 I concurrently run:

```sql
UPDATE students SET type = type - 1 WHERE id = 122;
```

The result I get is an exception, i.e student's `type` can't be lower than **1**  in session 2 since I already set the same student's `type` to value of **1** and since session was in exclusive lock for that student, session 2 had to wait.

---

**In Flask-SQLAlchemy**

I tried to recreate the same result with user, `type` attribute set to 4 by default.

In session 1:

```
user = Student.query.with_for_update(of=Student, nowait=True).filter(Student.id == 122).first()
user.type = 1
db.session.commit()
```

In session 2:

```
user = Student.query.filter(Student.id == 122).first()
user.type -= 1
db.session.commit()
```

The result I get is that user's `type` equals 3, whereas I should get an exception.
Transaction changes in session 1 are overridden by those in session 2, even though after `db.session.commit()` in transaction in session 2 it  waits till transaction in session 1 is over.

---

But in session 2 when I run this with session 1 concurrently:

```
user = Student.query.filter(Student.id == 122).update({"type": Student.type - 1})
db.session.commit()
```

I get the right output, i.e integrity error showing an attempt to set student 122s `type` attribute to 0 (not overriding session 1 result).

Would like to know why this happens.

Answer (score 6):

The 2 sessions should look like this:

```
user = Student.query.with_for_update(of=Student, nowait=True).filter(Student.id == 122).first()
user.type = 1
db.session.commit()
```

and

```
user = Student.query.with_for_update(of=Student, nowait=True).filter(Student.id == 122).first()
user.type -= 1
db.session.commit()
```

In order for `FOR UPDATE` to work properly, **all** involved transactions which intend to update the row need to use it.

In your example, session 2 is not using `with_for_update`.  Since you didn't tell it to use `FOR UPDATE`, it is free to read the old value of the row (since the new value has not yet been committed, and locks do not block pure readers), then modify it that in-memory value, then write it back.

If you don't want to use `FOR UPDATE` everywhere that you read row with the intention of changing it, you could instead use `isolation level serializable` everywhere.  However if you do, things might not block, but rather will appear to succeed until the commit, then throw serialization errors that will need to be caught and dealt with.

**Note:** Your pre-edit example should have worked as both sessions were labelled with `with_for_update`.

Comment: i'm getting the correct result that i wanted when i use ```user = Student.query.filter(Student.id == 122).update({"type": Student.type - 1})
db.session.commit()``` in session 2 instead of ```user = Student.query.filter(Student.id == 122).first()
user.type -= 1
db.session.commit()```. Can you tell me the reason ?@jjanes

Comment: @SanilJain I assume the first of those doesn't issue a separate SELECT and then at some later time an UPDATE, but just issues a single UPDATE statement.  Not a Flask expert though.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä can you explain it?